# How to prevent TextBox from stretching vertically inside Grid

Tags: wpf, xaml

In the markup below, the text box vertically to fills the entire grid row, no matter how big the row's height is. For a single line text box this does not look good. I need it to center vertically instead and have the height just enough to fit the current font. Setting the Height property on the text box helps but I do not want to hard code the height in case the font changes.

```
<Grid FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=TitleBox}">
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <TextBox Name="TitleBox"
           Text="{Binding Title, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
           Grid.Column="0" />
  <Button Command="{Binding CreateCommand}"
          IsDefault="True"
          Grid.Column="1">Create</Button>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set the `VerticalAlignment` of the text box to `Center`. The default is `Stretch` which explains why it stretches to fill the entire grid cell:

```
VerticalAlignment="Center"
```